# ALEKS plug-in on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, java, openjdk, jdk

I'm running 12.04 and have successfully installed the latest version of JDK. I've followed the instructions on [this page](http://www.ubuntututorials.com/install-aleks-plugin-ubuntu/) to install the plug-in for ALEKS, and that worked. But when I log in to ALEKS and try to access my class, ALEKS still won't run, even though I've installed the plug-in and am running the right version of Java. Any thoughts?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that Java plugin works in your browser. You can test it by going to this link https://www.java.com/verify/‎